# XML API response

Tags: python-3.x

I am calling an API which giving response in xml.From browser I am getting the response but from while calling it in below python code not getting the output.

```
URLink = "https://urlink***************"
import requests
from xml.etree import ElementTree

response = requests.get(URLink)
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
print(tree)
```

Could anybody help what I am doing wrong here ?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "c:\callxml_api.py", line 7, in 
>   tree = ElementTree.fromstring(response.content)
>
> File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1315, in 
>     XML
>
> return parser.close()
>
> File "", line None
>
> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0

Comment: Looks like you are getting zero input, either remote server closed connection or sent zero-length response.